# Should I ask for a fast response?

Tags: peer-review, journals, open-access

I got minor revisions and sent the updates by 20 September but didn't get any response yet. I asked the editor by 10 October for the status and he replied that “the paper is with the editor for the evaluation”. The status changed twice, on 24 September with the editor and 7 October with the editor too.

As I need the acceptance by 1 November, should I send another email to the editor asking him for a fast decision or will it not be allowed?

Comment: Why do you "need the acceptance" by Nov. 1?

Comment: What would happen if the timeline is not met?  Would you resubmit, withdraw, send to another journal/conference, etc.?  Generally, this won't work, but there may be exceptions.

Comment: @FerventHippo The OP may have to meet some deadlines for a scholarship or for submission of an annual report or something like this.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I am not saying there may not be valid reasons, but the answer to the question "Should I ask for a fast response" strongly depends on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can ask, but it may be in vain. They may try to accommodate your wishes but it might not be possible. Of course, a rejection is easy to do, but an acceptance needs time and feedback from possibly several people. But yes, you can let them know of your deadline and why it is important.

But, make sure you have options for the paper if they can't hit the deadline. These are probably few and won't happen in a short time in any case.

Comment: thanks for replying . but excuse me does it normal for this duration as the revisions are minor not major. does rejection be an option here after minor revisions :-(

Comment: It depends on every case as well as who is available and their schedules.

Comment: excuse me , I got change in the status with"Under Review" from 27/10 until now and i tried to message the editor of the journal with the reply "The manuscript is currently being evaluated by the reviewers and you will be notified once the decision has been rendered." Can I message the editor who sent the comments directly to inquire about the cause of this delay as i need this acceptance for phD graduation and my deadline is become closer

Answer (score 11):

You can ask but basically everyone would like a fast turnaround so the odds are it will serve no purpose.  The only way to guarantee your paper is refereed in time to be accepted by a given date is to submit *well before* this date.

“Well before” can mean several months depending on the journal.  (Some journals actually publish average times between initial submission and acceptance, so you can gauge what “well before” actually means.)

Comment: I think with the average journals there is no way to *guarantee* that your paper is accepted by a certain date. Unexpected delays may happen... Submit early and hope for the best, as you say. For example, I recently had a submission peer reviewed for three months and only then did the editor decide that the topic didn't fit the journal scope - back to square one at another journal, three months wasted...

Comment: Would it make any sense to communicate what your own deadlines are?  So the person you're emailing can decide whether they have time to write a useful response before then or not, or should let you know early that they won't be able to accommodate your desired timeline?

Comment: @kricheli fixed thanks.

Comment: @PeterCordes The authors are not in contact with the reviewers, only the editors.  And the editors in turn depend on reviewers.  Trust me: manuscript management softwares now send automated email reminders to the referee and editors so people are fully aware when the process is falling behind.